# How do I go about solving this calculus problem? Has to do with areas and sums.

Tags: calculus

This is in relation to integrals in calculus I and areas under curves.

So the formula is such: f(x) = x^2 + 1

The question:
(a) Compute R1, M1, R3, M3
(b) Graph f(x) on the interval [0, 3]

I understand graphing but what is R1, M1 etc and how do I go about solving for those.

Comment: Read the examples in the chapter. This notation is almost certainly explained in the textbook.

Comment: @UmbertoP. The book isn't too clear is why I ask. Maybe someone else knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely $R_1$ is a right Riemann sum with one subdivision, $M_1$ is a midpoint Riemann sum with 1 subdivision, etc. See here: http://www2.seminolestate.edu/lvosbury/CalculusI_Folder/RiemannSumDemo.htm

As an example, here is how to do $R_3$:
Split the example into 3 intervals: (0,1), (1,2) and (2,3). Then, compute f(x) for each right number of the interval: $f(1)=2, f(2)=5, f(3)=10$. Multiply each by the length of the interval: $f(1)\times 1=2, f(2)\times 1=5, f(3)\times 1=10$. Finally, add them up: $2+5+10=17$.

Comment: So basically start at zero but split it up into 3. How big should they be though in width? So start at x=0, then go to x=1 and x=2, OR make them bigger/smaller?

Comment: Generally the notation ($R_m$) means $m$ subdivisions of equal width. So, for example, if the interval is [0,3], and you want to compute $R_3$, divide the length of the interval by the number of subdivisions: (3)/3 = 1 and then start at the left and construct equal width intervals of 1. In this case, it's (0,1), (1,2), and (2,3)

Comment: That's what I thought but the only issue is that they don't actually specify an interval([0, 3]) until question (b) so I was unsure on what interval to use

Comment: you should just assume that the interval for part (a) is also [0,3] because it's impossible to do without an interval. the goal is to approximate the area under a curve, but you can't do that if you don't know what interval to use.